# Shorter form of writing jQuery $(document).ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use a lot of jQuery, so I have to keep typing out the `$(document).ready` function to put the jQuery code. Is there a shorter form of the function?

Comment: Why are you making lots of `$(document).ready()` blocks?  Only initialization code that's referencing the DOM on first page load needs to be in such a block.  You can also puts lots of pieces of code in one `$(document).ready()` block.

Answer (score 16):

The three following syntaxes are allowed:

Syntax 1

```
$(document).ready(function)
```

Syntax 2

```
$().ready(function)
```

Syntax 3

```
$(function)
```

**Update:**

Additionally, from version 1.9 onwards:

```
$(window).on('load', null, function)
$(document).on('ready', null, function)
```

Comment: There is also `$(document).bind("ready", handler)` (though that doesn't behave _quite_ the same way).

Comment: The first is good, the second is in danger with conflicting another JS framework/library. The third is the same as second. You should use jQuery(document).ready(function() {...}); 
Write that line once and implement all your logic between square brackets. What's the problem ?