# How to convert this onclick() function to onload()

Tags: onclick, onload, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make onclick automatically through onload function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098019/how-to-make-onclick-automatically-through-onload-function)

So I have the following function which is being called when I click a button.
Here is the code:

```
<a href="#" role="button" onClick="myFunction('parameter')">
```

How can I call this function as soon as page is loaded?
I tried onLoad function but doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple options for onload event.

In HTML

```
<body onload="myFunction('parameter')">
```

In Javascript

```
window.onload=function(){
myFunction('parameter');
};
```

In JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      myFunction('parameter');
});
```

Comment: I tried using the html version of this.
It worked but the browser blocks the pop up by default.
Any way to get around this?

Comment: I hope [this link](http://www.lbl.gov/ehs/training/webcourses/globalAssets/CourseRequirements/disablePopups/disablepopups.html) helps you to disable the popup blocker.

Comment: That will work for me but the browser blocks pop up for everyone but I can't change their settings :P
 Somehow I need to bypass the default pop up blocker.

Answer (score 3):

Put this anywhere on your page, preferably in the `<head>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
$(function() {
    myFunction('parameter');
});
</script>
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7911809/584192 for more ways of doing it via jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this:

```
window.onload = function(){
    myFunction('parameter');
}
```

See more at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onload

Answer (score 1):

You call in myFunction [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) or just before closing of body tag.

*Within document.ready*

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nmAye/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(document).ready(function(){
          myFunction('parameter');
    });
</script>
```

*Before closing body tag*

```
<script type="text/javascript">    

     myFunction('parameter');

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code.

```
<script>
   onload = function(){
     myFunction('parameter');
   }
</script>
```