# Make a modal appear onload instead of onclick?

Tags: javascript, html

I am following [this tutorial on the W3schools site](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp) to make a modal window appear.

It uses the following code to make a modal appear when the user clicks on a button:

**HTML**

```
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

**Javascript**:

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

I would like to make it that the modal appears when the page loads and not when the user clicks on the link.

According to [this Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14453145/how-to-convert-this-onclick-function-to-onload), I can achieve this by changing `btn.onclick` to `onload = function`. However, when I try it, it doesn't work.

Here is [a JSFiddle with my code](https://jsfiddle.net/big_smile/e3xmdtkn/5/).

PS I know I can use jQuery, but it is only a simple modal, so I don't want to load up the jQuery library for something simple.

Comment: The answer in the thread you linked has `window.onload = function`, not just `onload = function`. It makes all the difference.

Comment: No difference. Properties of window are global.

Comment: @Klaycon I tried window onload, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @big_smile see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31946528/simple-onload-doesnt-work-in-jsfiddle and https://jsfiddle.net/co53veqt/

Comment: It's because in the fiddle you selected `Load type` `onLoad` and your handler won't be executed, because the event is already fired. Change the load type and it will be fine.

Comment: @radulfr oops, indeed you're correct. My mistake, forgot window is the context in browser.

Comment: @Jordan Enev It doesn't work in my HTML document either. I looked at the other stack over flow question and added this: `onload = function(){
  alert("LOADED!");
  modal.style.display = "block";
}` The alert appears, but the modal does not.

Comment: You should get the modal (document.getElementById("myModal")) in `onload`. Otherwise - the DOM isn't loaded yet.