# Converting onclick to onload event

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I would like to covert onclick to onload event and add it with custom js Chrome addon.

Based on this topic [How to convert this onclick() function to onload() [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14453145/how-to-convert-this-onclick-function-to-onload) I have take this code:

```html
<li class="orders_sorting_sc ">
  <a href="#" onclick="table_setSorting('orders_table','ASC'); $('.orders_sorting_sc').removeClass('active'); $(this).parent().addClass('active'); return false;">
    <i class="dropdown-icon fa fa-sort-amount-up"></i>
    Rosnąco
  </a>
</li>
```

and make this code:

```js
window.onload=function()
  {
  table_setSorting('orders_table','ASC'); 
  $('.orders_sorting_sc').removeClass('active'); 
  $(this).parent().addClass('active'); 
  return false;
  };
```

What is wrong with the code? It doesn't work at all.

*EDIT - This is a HTML code of a menu:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu  dropdown-menu-small dropdown-scroll">
<li class="dropdown-header">Sortuj według</li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li class="orders_sorting_fields "><a onclick="table_setSorting('orders_table','o.id'); $('.orders_sorting_fields').removeClass('active'); $(this).parent().addClass('active'); return false;" href="#">ID zamówienia</a></li>
<li class="orders_sorting_fields "><a onclick="table_setSorting('orders_table','o.shop_order_id'); $('.orders_sorting_fields').removeClass('active'); $(this).parent().addClass('active'); return false;" href="#">ID w sklepie</a></li>
<li class="orders_sorting_fields active"><a onclick="table_setSorting('orders_table','o.date_add'); $('.orders_sorting_fields').removeClass('active'); $(this).parent().addClass('active'); return false;" href="#">Data złożenia</a></li>
<li class="orders_sorting_fields "><a onclick="table_setSorting('orders_table','o.date_in_status'); $('.orders_sorting_fields').removeClass('active'); $(this).parent().addClass('active'); return false;" href="#">Data w statusie</a></li>
<li class="orders_sorting_fields "><a onclick="table_setSorting('orders_table','price_all'); $('.orders_sorting_fields').removeClass('active'); $(this).parent().addClass('active'); return false;" href="#">Łączna cena</a></li>
<li class="orders_sorting_fields "><a onclick="table_setSorting('orders_table','o.price_shipment'); $('.orders_sorting_fields').removeClass('active'); $(this).parent().addClass('active'); return false;" href="#">Cena wysyłki</a></li>
<li class="orders_sorting_fields "><a onclick="table_setSorting('orders_table','o.delivery_method'); $('.orders_sorting_fields').removeClass('active'); $(this).parent().addClass('active'); return false;" href="#">Sposób wysyłki</a></li>
<li class="orders_sorting_fields "><a onclick="table_setSorting('orders_table','o.status_id'); $('.orders_sorting_fields').removeClass('active'); $(this).parent().addClass('active'); return false;" href="#">Status</a></li>
<li class="orders_sorting_fields "><a onclick="table_setSorting('orders_table','o.transaction_status'); $('.orders_sorting_fields').removeClass('active'); $(this).parent().addClass('active'); return false;" href="#">Transakcje Allegro</a></li>
<li class="orders_sorting_fields "><a onclick="table_setSorting('orders_table','o.paid'); $('.orders_sorting_fields').removeClass('active'); $(this).parent().addClass('active'); return false;" href="#">Płatności</a></li>
<li class="orders_sorting_fields "><a onclick="table_setSorting('orders_table','o.delivery_fullname'); $('.orders_sorting_fields').removeClass('active'); $(this).parent().addClass('active'); return false;" href="#">Imię i nazwisko</a></li>
<li class="orders_sorting_fields "><a onclick="table_setSorting('orders_table','o.allegro_user_login'); $('.orders_sorting_fields').removeClass('active'); $(this).parent().addClass('active'); return false;" href="#">Login Allegro</a></li>
<li class="orders_sorting_fields "><a onclick="table_setSorting('orders_table','o.delivery_package_nr'); $('.orders_sorting_fields').removeClass('active'); $(this).parent().addClass('active'); return false;" href="#">Numer nadawczy</a></li>
<li class="orders_sorting_fields "><a onclick="table_setSorting('orders_table','o.extra_field_1'); $('.orders_sorting_fields').removeClass('active'); $(this).parent().addClass('active'); return false;" href="#">Opis (Sety)</a></li>
<li class="orders_sorting_fields "><a onclick="table_setSorting('orders_table','o.extra_field_2'); $('.orders_sorting_fields').removeClass('active'); $(this).parent().addClass('active'); return false;" href="#">Kod prod. (Sety)</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li class="dropdown-header">Sortowanie i wyświetlanie</li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li class="orders_sorting_sc "><a href="#" onclick="table_setSorting('orders_table','DESC'); $('.orders_sorting_sc').removeClass('active'); $(this).parent().addClass('active'); return false;"><i class="dropdown-icon fa fa-sort-amount-down"></i> Malejąco</a></li>
<li class="orders_sorting_sc active"><a href="#" onclick="table_setSorting('orders_table','ASC'); $('.orders_sorting_sc').removeClass('active'); $(this).parent().addClass('active'); return false;"><i class="dropdown-icon fa fa-sort-amount-up"></i> Rosnąco</a></li></ul>
```

Comment: The context of `$(this)` is a completely different one; now it is `window`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Could you guide me how to correct this in my code?  I don't have coding skills.

Comment: The comment above indicates this is not a *coding* issue, it's a *concept* issue - when the page loads, exactly what is meant to have the `active` class added?   Do you have multiple sorting `li`s?  Which one?  How does your code identify that one?

Comment: "*js Chrome addon*" - is that a [tag:google-chrome-extension]?

Comment: I have add the whole code of the list to the question post.
This the chrome extension - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/code-injector/jgcallaoodbhagkaoobenaabockcejmc